# Elasticsearch - recover id of record with max value on another field

Tags: elasticsearch

In Elasticsearch I had records like:

```
{"_id": "....", "field1": "201501", "tag": "a", "name": "...."},
{"_id": "....", "field1": "201503", "tag": "a", "name": "...."},
{"_id": "....", "field1": "201504", "tag": "a", "name": "...."},     
{"_id": "....", "field1": "201501", "tag": "b", "name": "...."},
{"_id": "....", "field1": "201503", "tag": "b", "name": "...."},
{"_id": "....", "field1": "201504", "tag": "b", "name": "...."},     
...
```

I'd like to do, in a performant way, a query on Elasticsearch to recover `_id` (elasticsearch one) where `field1` has the maximum value and field `tag` is filtered on one value (i.e. `b`). I can presume no duplicate.

The simple method is to recover him with filter on `tag` and sort by `field1 desc`.

**EDIT**

I use the following query:

```
 {
    "size": 1,
    "query": {
      "term": {
         "field": "tag",
         "value", "b"
      }
    },
    "sort": {
         "field1": "desc"
    }
 }
```

The problem is: is too much slow, since I must do this operation to make some programmatic check, update this found record, and insert a new one.

There is a faster way?
I.e. do exists a way to use a `updateByQuery` on this "max" record?

Comment: you could try [function_score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-field-value-factor)  i.e  `field_value_factor` on `field1` and set size to 1 . I presume this would be faster than `sort`  but i have not tried it so cannot confirm

Comment: what's the query you have now that is too slow?